# Forwarding traffic with IPtables through a series of IDS

Tags: iptables

My goal is to run several Intrusion Detection Systems (IDS), these IDS sensors should be positioned in sequence, so the traffic will travel through the first IDS and will generate alerts of malicious traffic, **then** the traffic will be forwarded to the next IDS and it will analyze the traffic and generate alerts and so on until the traffic reaches the server IP at the end.

I have just installed eth0, eth1, eth2 adapters on virtualbox, eth1 and eth2 not configured yet but I see them when I type "ifconfig" knowing that I configured it with virtualbox GUI to "bridged" not "NAT".

My question is, from where to start with iptables to setup this architecture of Sequence IDS?

Comment: Do you want to make your ids servers transparent? You will provide address space for them or just want to make them a transparent bridge?

Comment: If i got your point well , it means that you will want to route packets from internet like: NET->MAIN_GW->IDS1->IDS2->IDS3->PRIVATE/PUBLIC_NETWORK

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong please